# Why does this duplicate the posts outside as well as inside the while loop - PHP?

Tags: php, wordpress

The following produces 2 posts in the loop with the surrounding div row-fluid. Then it creates another 2 posts after. Why is this?
EDIT:code above as requested:

```
<?php  get_header(); ?>
<section class="clearfix" id="home">

<div class="row-fluid">

<?php $count = 1; ?>
<?php if ( have_posts() ) : ?>
<?php while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>   
<div class="span4">
    <div class="wrap-title">
        <div class="position">
            <div class="title"><?php the_title();?></div>
            <div class="tags"><?php echo $cats; ?> </div>   
        </div>
    </div>  
</div>
<?php if($count == 2) {
    echo '</div>';
}?>
<?php $count++; ?>
<?php endwhile; ?>
```

I posted here as apposed to wordpress as I'm anticipating it being a PHP syntax error, something with the count variable possibly or where the row-fluid div is positioned.

Comment: could you explain what do you mean by `entries`. It creates another 2 entries - what entries? Also, paste code which is positioned above `row-fluid`. I believe the error is there

Comment: code added, its just the start of the body tag from header.php and section node tag. entries changed to posts. thanks.

Comment: are you including/calling `header.php` twice in your code?

Comment: What do you expect it to produce? You're looping through the posts, and incrementing `$count` as you go. When `$count` is 2, you're adding a `</div>`, but there's nothing to terminate the loop, so it'll then print out any extra posts.

Comment: Why is what? The additional posts after the first two?

Comment: What is why? First two after why? :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although I would create a code differently, the solution to your problem I believe is to modify your code to this:

```
<?php  get_header(); ?>
<section class="clearfix" id="home">

<?php $count = 1; ?>
<?php if ( have_posts() ) : ?>
<?php while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>   
<?php if($count % 2 == 0) {
  <div class="row-fluid">
}?>
<div class="span4">
    <div class="wrap-title">
        <div class="position">
            <div class="title"><?php the_title();?></div>
            <div class="tags"><?php echo $cats; ?> </div>   
        </div>
    </div>  
</div>
<?php if($count % 2 == 0) {
    echo '</div>';
}?>
<?php $count++; ?>
<?php endwhile; ?>
```

**EDIT:**

You said it produces 2 posts after  also - that is why you will add `</div>` after first two posts, and then after that you will continue printing. The solution would be to use the code above - with `%` **or** to print only two posts use this code:

```
<?php  get_header(); ?>
<section class="clearfix" id="home">


<div class="row-fluid">

<?php $count = 1; ?>
<?php if ( have_posts() ) : ?>
<?php while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>   
<div class="span4">
    <div class="wrap-title">
        <div class="position">
            <div class="title"><?php the_title();?></div>
            <div class="tags"><?php echo $cats; ?> </div>   
        </div>
    </div>  
</div>
<?php if($count == 2) {
    break;
}?>
<?php $count++; ?>
<?php endwhile; ?>
</div>
```

But the above code could be optimized not to search for all posts, but it should will work as is.

Comment: Why after *every* two posts? The $count variable is not reset to one or zero here, so the number 2 should be passed only once.

Comment: Why? Because. Read from question. And `the number should be passed only once` I think I don't even understand what you meant by this one

Comment: how many stars does this output? `$count = 1; while($count<10) { if ($count == 2) echo "*"; $count++;}` one or more? You say more. I say one. The original code in question is not using modulo.

Comment: Yes the question doesn't use modulo. Ok, then everything is solved, The question is the answer. Problem solved.

Comment: It works, thank you. Just out of interest (i know this is separate from this question) but do you have any links or clues as to how you would code it differently as you mentioned in the answer?